# Reduce JavaScript code. Double event, selector into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

Any idea how to write this code better."the html is nested tabs"
Two selectors and two similar events, in a function would be better or a pattern to reduce lines. [eg .jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utaxot/3/edit)

```
$(function() {
  var $items  = $('#vtab>ul>li'),
      $items2 = $('#vtab2>ul>li');

  $items.mouseover(function() {
    var index = $items.index($(this));
    $items.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
  }).eq(1).mouseover();

  $items2.mouseover(function() {
    var index = $items2.index($(this));
    $items2.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#vtab2>div').hide().eq(index).show();
  }).eq(1).mouseover();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML (add `tab-panel` class to tab containers):

```
<div id="vtab" class="tab-panel">

<div id="vtab2" class="tab-panel">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $(".tab-panel").each(function () {

        var $currentPanel = $(this),
        $items = $currentPanel.find(">ul>li");

        $items.mouseover(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
            index = $items.index($this);

            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');
            $currentPanel.find(">div").hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(1).mouseover();

    });

});
```

jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/utaxot/7/edit)

Comment: I put your code but did not work  in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utaxot/3/edit)

Comment: Is your html as you want it to be? This bit of code assumes that `#vtab` and `#vtab2` are on the same level but it looks like they are nested, is this correct? 

Can you validate your html as well and update the jsbin please?

Comment: are nested tabs. lacking specify this in the question.

Comment: @AURIGADL answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Give those `#vtab`s a class and it should be simple:

```
$(function() {
    $('.vtab > ul > li').mouseover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $this.closest('.vtab').find('div').eq($this.index()).hide().siblings().show();
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).find('> ul > li').eq(1).mouseover();
    });
});
```

Although I'd try turning it into a plugin at this point.

Comment: I put your code but did not work  in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/utaxot/3/edit)